# How do I replace a value between 2 arrays (C)

Tags: c, arrays, replace, between

I'm trying to copy the individual values of a full array into an empty array. I was wondering how could I do that? This is what I've tried, basically:

```
for (f = 0 ; f > *LargoM ; f++)
    {
        EntradaM[f] = men_cif[f];
    }
```

Any answers appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Here's the full code guys. Go nuts:

https://gist.github.com/Crawlingvx/dafb909cb3297d47a908

Edit 2: Question answered, problem solved. Thank you [Ron Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4318814/ron-thompson).

Comment: It is unclear what the used variables denote.

Comment: What's `*LargoM`? And if you keep incrementing `f`, will that eventually make the value of `f` greater than `*LargoM`?

Comment: if you know the # of bytes you want to copy just use memcpy() or bcopy() and pass the address of respective src and dst arrays.

Comment: I can post the actual complete code, but it's quite long. "LargoM" is just a variable with a specific value on it. Just assume it means any integer you'd like. And yes, incrementing "f" will eventually make it larger than "LargoM". The program compiles without any issue, but it's not copying the values of "men_cif" into "EntradaM". I just get a bunch of non-sensical symbols

Comment: Please clarify your question and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is impossible to know where your bug is given the limited information you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical form is this:

```
int myArray[3] = {1,2,3};
int copy[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    copy[i] = myArray[i];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Note that typically when you are using `i++` then the middle exit condition will have `i < variable`.

Edit : after looking at your code you have this: `for (int i = 0; i > 20; i++)`. This will never execute. Either switch the `>` to `<` or set up an `i--` type for loop.

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing.

Comment: @crawlingvx: It's not though. You have a `i > 3` effectively as your exit condition. That means the loop would never execute.

Comment: son of a b***h. Betrayed by a Syntax Error after 264 lines of code. I see it now, Thank you very much, and sorry for not being able to see it myself.

Comment: Lol no bigs, happens to everyone.